# Servlet + HTML file

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to run my first servlet with a html file. In web.xml i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>XMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.antilamer.XMLServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/XMLServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet class:

```
package org.antilamer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class XMLServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        out.println("Hello! " + username);
    }


}
```

And finaly my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="XMLServlet">

    <input name="username">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But i have a little problem, my servlet working but i don't have the html file. It don't appear. I thought problem in servlet-mapping, but i use default url and have no idea why it dosen't work.

Comment: How do you expect to get the html file ? Please, Read more about servlets and jsps.

Comment: I watched that tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnUJl3NYRRc&index=6&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96. This guy have those inputs right in a browser.

Comment: You need to change your web.xml or forward your request like this (interseting in an MVC pattern) : http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/forwarding-from-servlet-jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your html file for example `index.html` and add the following lines to your web.xml
  `<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>`

The name of the html file must match the one in welcome-file list. Also if this html file is listed in welcome-file-list like this (without any path), it must be in a Web Root directory (for example WebContent).